# Tornado redirect from post completes, uncaught appears in the console

Tags: python, tornado

I implemented an SAML authentication single sign on using tornado 5.1.1

In short, SAML calls for multiple redirects, roughly like this:
step 1 - browser starts on /sp_sso url (service provider single sign on), which is redirected to the saml sso url on the identify provider authority

step 2  - the identity authority examines the request and if it decides to approve the the sign on , it redirects the request as a POST request back to the originating service as a assertion client response, called /sp_acs  where the user details are encoded in the post body.

step 3 - In post /sp_acs url, the body is examined, user data is retrieved and the service session is created - at that point, the request is once again redirects, but this time to the landing page, lets call it /home

In my case /home is a static page, which is not served by the tornado service (nginx intercepts it and serves the UX).

The redirect actually works fine, the browser loads the /home url and the user experience continues from that point on with no issues.

BUT, I do see the following error in the logs, and for the life of me, I could figure it the cause and if it is really an issue.

```
[E 181204 16:56:11 web:1670] Uncaught exception POST /sp_acs (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:3000', method='POST', uri='/sp_acs', version='HTTP/1.0', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erez/amicus/wf/svc-amicus-authentication/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1590, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Here is the last bit of code in the /sp_acs post handler:

```
 def post(self):
    logger.info("at acs")
    auth=None
    try:
        auth = init_saml_auth(self.request)
        auth.process_response()
        if auth.get_errors():
            logger.error(str(auth.get_errors()))
            return self.set_status(400,",".join(auth.get_errors()))

        if not auth.is_authenticated():
            logger.error("authentication failed " + str(auth))

            return self.set_status(403, "Not Authenticated")


        logger.info(str({'samlUserdata': auth.get_attributes(),
                                'samlNameId': auth.get_nameid(),
                                'samlSessionIndex': auth.get_session_index()}))


        user_uid = auth.get_attributes()['uid'][0]
        login_response = ... # some application logic
        logger.info('login_response: '+str(login_response))
        if login_response:
            rdr = self.request.protocol + '://' + self.request.host + LANDING_PAGE
            self.redirect(rdr,status=303)
        else:
            self.redirect(LOGIN_ERROR_PAGE,status=303)



    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("acs error "+str(auth))
        raise e
```

I am using OneLogin as an SAML protocol parser, slightly modified to be used with Tornado as it is built around flask originally. It works well enough and I use SimplSAML as a SAML test harness... (https://hub.docker.com/r/kristophjunge/test-saml-idp/)

---

EDIT

This is what init_saml_auth() does:

```
def init_saml_auth(request):
  def prepare_tornado_request(request):
    result = {
        'https': 'on' if request.protocol == 'https' else 'off',
        'http_host': tornado.httputil.split_host_and_port(request.host)[0],
        'script_name': request.path,
        'server_port': tornado.httputil.split_host_and_port(request.host)[1],
        'get_data': request.arguments,
        'post_data': request.arguments,
        'query_string': request.query
    }
    return result



  auth = OneLogin_Saml2_Auth(prepare_tornado_request(request), custom_base_path=SAML_PATH)
  return auth
```

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: yes. it is thrown after the browser already got the 303 code and redirected the page

Comment: I think `init_saml_auth` is modifying the `self.request` object. Try and pass it's copy instead of the original object at this line -- `auth = init_saml_auth(self.request)`, like `import copy; request_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.request); auth = init_saml_auth(request_copy)`.

Comment: OneLogin expects request to be in flask style, i edited the question to include the code... but I will change it none the less with deepcopy and see what happens. thanks.

Comment: I will try an post to redirect - in a separate test class, just to see what happens... I dont think it has much to do with the saml logic